# Convex optimization inside a hyper-rectangle region

Tags: reference-request, optimization, terminology, convex-optimization

I'm recently looking for algorithms for solving convex optimization problem inside a hyper-rectangle (that is, each constraint contains only one variable):

$\begin{align}
&\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\operatorname{minimize}}& & f(\mathbf{x}) \\
&\operatorname{subject\ to}
& &a_i\leq x_i \leq b_i, \quad i = 1, \dots, m \\
\end{align}$

Are there any keywords or resources about this special case of convex optimization? (hopefully for both differentiable and non-differentiable functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [bound-constrained optimization](https://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/leyffer/images/0/01/07-bndCons.pdf).